# js - How to decorate/proxy/spy on all functions? For creating a runtime profiler

Tags: javascript, profiling, decorator, javascript-objects, trace

So I have this `decorate` function that takes an object and a method-name and wraps it with external logic.

```
function decorate(object, methodName) {
    var originalMethod = object[methodName];
    object[methodName] = function () {
        // pre-logic
        var retVal = originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
        // post-logic
        return retVal;
    };
}
```

Now I want to wrap **ALL** of the functions in my application, i.e.

- All the recursive public functions of the object
- All private scope functions
- All anonymous functions
- Anything else I might have forgotten.

My purpose in doing this is to implement a "JS Profiler" that will run alongside my application during automated testing, and output performance data to logs.

I need this for testing purposes, so the solution must have minimal changes to the actual code of my application.

Possible solutions I've considered:

- Public methods can be easily traversed and replaced using a recursive object traversal function.
- Some hack using `eval()` to be able to access private methods.
- Ideally, to handle all cases, I could use a proxy HTTP server (Node.js for example) that will transform each javascript file before sending it to the browser. This way my codebase will remain clean, but my tests will have the necessary changes.

The first 2 are only partial solutions, and the last one seems like an overkill and also a potential "bug factory"...

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to achieve what I need?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. It's going to make JavaScript execution so slow, if you can get it to work at all. Essentially you'll be writing a VM in JavaScript to run JavaScript. Is there a reason you don't want to use native profilers?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I want to use this in my automated tests, and output the results to a log file.
Using native profilers is not possible because: 1) it is not cross browser, and 2) there is no API for pulling the data for saving it to log files.